# mac 10.8.3 - current recommendations on installing ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, installation, rvm

I have postgres, ruby, and rails, rvm, and homebrew installed on an iMac and a macbook.  I  have a new macbook  pro (osx 10.8.3) to setup and want to know what is the current suggested best way to go about it.
there are lots of suggestions out there, many of them old.

There are so many ways to install each of these.... I ended up with 3 installations of postgres on one machine!

Should I install ruby first then postgres or postgres first?

Should I follow these instructions
http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/

Should I use railsinstaller? postgres app?  homebrew?

I'd rather be asking current recommendations on how to install fresh before making any mistakes and then having a bad install.

Thanks!

Comment: My only bit of advice here is to stick with RVM for sure. It seems like every platform specific way of installing ruby has some booby trap just waiting to catch you.

Comment: I disagree with @RonDahlgren - I think the easiest, safest, and most reliable way to install ruby, if you want to maintain multiple ruby versions, is `rbenv` (and its `ruby-build` plugin). Of course you must install Xcode before doing *anything* else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there really is a one size fits all method. Some things are simply personal preference. For example I love homebrew and I install a lot of things via that. I'm also a big fan of rvm but some people prefer rbenv. Is one better than the other? Of course. But which is better for you, depends on you.

A simple guide that will get you most of the way there can be found here: https://coderwall.com/p/auvm9g. If you don't need MySQL skip that part. For Postgresql I use Postgres.app which you can find here: http://postgresapp.com/

This will get you setup with rvm and homebrew and has served me well. But again, so much of it is just personal preference. You might find homebrew doens't suit you or you would prefer rbenv over rvm.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm thinking I'd like to go the rvm and homebrew route.  Will check out those links and get back to ya.